# bootstrap datatable functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having this problem with bootstrap DataTable. Can anyone please tell me the proper way to combine these two functions to avoid reinitialise error?

This is what I have now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable();

    var oTable = $('table.display').dataTable();
    oTable.fnSort( [ [8,'desc'] ] );
});

var table = $("table.display").dataTable({
    language: {
        sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_"
    }
});
</script>
```

Now I want to add this function in.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );
```

Doing this gives me reinitialise error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable({
        "scrollX": true
    });

    var oTable = $('table.display').dataTable();
        oTable.fnSort( [ [8,'desc'] ] );
});

var table = $("table.display").dataTable({
    language: {
        sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_"
    }
});
</script>
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ok so i was so focused on the script that i didnt notice the document where you need to declare nowrap to the table for this to take effect. adding the nowrap class fixed this problem

```
<table id="" class="table-striped table-bordered table-hover display nowrap" cellspacing="0">

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('table.display').DataTable();

      var oTable = $('table.display').dataTable();
            oTable.fnSort( [ [8,'desc'] ] );


});

  var table = $("table.display").dataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    language : {
        sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_"

    }
});
</script>
```